# JQuery Autocomplete - Retrieve Data from 2 Search Terms

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am trying to capture a 2nd term to display results, so textbox1 has autocomplete feature and textbox2 has simple input - this is the code to autocomplete and return values on 1 term...

```
//connect to your database

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT description as value,id FROM test WHERE description LIKE '%".$term."%'";

$result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
    $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
    $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}

echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
```

I need something like this

```
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
$term2 = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term2']));

$qstring = "SELECT description as value, lastname, id FROM test 
            WHERE description LIKE '%".$term."%'" AND lastname LIKE '%".$term2."%'";

etc...
```

Can anyone help?